# Rails - Specifying additional pages to be included in routes 'resources' statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I generated the standard pages using rails generate scaffold, but want to add a new page.

Instead of adding in routes.rb the following:

```
get "newpage" => 'controller#newpage'
```

Is there a way to include 'newpage' in with the following statement?

```
resources :controller
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources :controllers do
   collection do 
      get :action_name
   end
end
```

Example:

```
resources :users do
  collection do 
    get :my_name
  end
end
```

in your console verify the generated urls with following command:

```
  rake routes | grep 'users'
```

Depending on the result you can execute **my_name_users_path** In your view/controllers.

More info check [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: more info here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. For single member:   `resources :photos do
  member do
    get 'preview'
  end
end`

Comment: Yes, @Stan Rails doc has more info on this, I would like to copy that link, if you don't mind. :)

Comment: `member` requires a numeric id, i.e. `/controller/1/newpage`. This may not make sense for certain resources. `collection` provides a more sensible route i.e. `/controller/newpage`